# Title of Custom TitleBar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented custom title bar feature using the following `class CustomWindow`. Other activities are extended by this `class CustomWindow`. For example `public class SimpleSearch extends CustomWindow {}`. The problem is the I want to read the title of the other orginal activity and display it int the `Textview title` of `class CustomWindow`. How can I do that?

```
public class CustomWindow extends ListActivity {
    protected TextView title;
    protected ImageView icon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        icon  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
title.setText(this.getTitle());
```

This is poorly documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getTitle%28%29).